# How to remove Woo commerce Product Page Image Anchor?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I'm a WordPress Developer past 2 Years. I'm facing some issue into Woocommerce Product page Template.

1. I have created Product in Woocommerce.
2. Open Product Detail/Single page.
3. When clicking on Product Image it opens in popup/Same page.

Please Help me to remove the anchor from product Image.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the below code to remove the link from thumbnail on single product page .

```
add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html','wc_remove_link_on_thumbnails' );

function wc_remove_link_on_thumbnails( $html ) {
     return strip_tags( $html,'<img>' );
}
```

Comment: It is removed anchor but not removed a title on the image. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: it shows because of image title, if it help you to solve the problem then mark it as solution so it can help other developer too.

Comment: Just remove image title from the dashboard, it is working fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: great @VishalGupta :)